# Prevent Gradle dependency for support library from being overridden by newer version

Tags: java, android, maven, twitter, android-gradle-plugin

In my `build.gradle` I have the support library as a dependency, as seen here force to revision 19.

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+`

With revision 21 the Material Design support was introduced. I don't want to use the Material Design in this case here which is fine. The problem arises through the use of  the `Fabric SDK`:

I include their Maven repository `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }` and compile the Twitter dependencies:

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Now what happens is that I get the support library in revision 21. What happened here? Does the Fabric SDK use the neweset support library?

How can I force it to revision 19 anyway?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Feel free to exclude the Android Support Library and provide your own version.

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0@aar') { 
       transitive = true; 
       exclude module: 'support-v4' 
}
```

*Make sure you provide your own version though, otherwise you'll get runtime errors*

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the `build.gradle` as

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"
```

Also, please make sure you downloaded the build tools for API 19 in SDK manager.